# Form submission through REST api

Tags: ember.js

Im new to Ember and I am trying to create a record by submitting a form. This is the code I've written so far:

```
App.CharactersNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.createRecord('character', {name: '', race: ''});
    }
});

<form {{action "createCharacter" on="submit"}}>

        <div class="form-group">    
            <label>Name</label>
            {{input value=characterName class="form-control"}}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">    
            <label>Race</label>
            {{input id=characterRace class="form-control"}}
        </div>

        {{#link-to 'characters'}}<button class="btn btn-default">Back</button>{{/link-to}}

        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Create</button>
    </form>

App.CharactersNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

actions: {

    createCharacter: function() {
        var name = this.get('characterName'),
                race = this.get('characterRace');

        if (!name || !race) { return false }

        // create new character
        var character = this.store.createRecord('character', {
            name: name,
            race: race
        });

        this.set('characterName', '');
        this.set('characterRace', '');

        character.save();

    }
}
})
```

Right now, the code stops at the `var character = this.store.createRecord` line in the controller, but no errors are raised in the console

Thanks

Comment: youre creating a record in your route, so you dont need to create a second one in your controller. You could leave the route blank or in the controller use: `this.get('model').set('name', characterName)`. Other than that I dont know. Have you created a user model? defined a store?

Comment: Two things too. Ember data is a great extension that you can get for your browser to help with debugging and `Ember.Logger.log(what_ever_you_want_logged_to_the_console)` is a great command for debugging in the console.

Comment: Hey @Tarlen, Did you get the answer of the question, if yes then please reply over here. It will help others too. like me :)!